# I need to make Service reactive without repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, project-reactor, reactor

My task is to make UserService reactive by using Flux/Mono.

I understand how flux and mono work but only did them with repositories and not arraylists.

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        this.users.add(User.builder()
                        .id(1L)
                        .username("username1")
                        .age(14)
                        .build());
    }

    @Override
    public User findOne(Long userId) {
        LOGGER.info("UserService: execute findOne(userId) method");
        return this.users.stream()
                .filter(user -> user.getId().equals(userId))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        LOGGER.info("UserService: execute findAll() method");

        return this.users;
    }

    @Override
    public void add() {
        LOGGER.info("UserService: execute add() method");

        this.users.add(User.builder()
                .id(3L)
                .username("username3")
                .age(34)
                .build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create Flux from List. Ex:

```
Flux<User> userStream = Flux.fromIterable(users)
```

Or if need to return one

```
Flux.just(user)
Mono.just(user)
```

To add value in the existing stream

```
userStream = Flux.concat(userStream, Flux.just(newUser));
```

For more detail: 
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html